# String extraction in Python / Pandas with repeated delimiter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with a column that includes any combination of one or many variables, separated by a '/' delimiter, e.g.:

```
Rd/MLERS
Rd
Rd          
Rd/DLEPC/DLERS
SLERS
MLERS
```

Etc., etc.  I want to extract the primary classifier, i.e.: the only or the first variable immediately preceding the first '/' character.  I don't have a lot of experience with str.extract and my effort -

```
df["primaryEjecta1"] = df["MORPHOLOGY_EJECTA_1"].str.extract('(.*)/', expand=True)
```

does not work as anticipated -

```
Rd
NaN
NaN
Rd/DLEPC
NaN
NaN
```

Specifically -

- Where there is only one variable, I am inadvertently converting this to NaN;
- Where there are three (or more) variables, I am extracting the first two (or more), rather than only the first.

Sure this simple to fix if you know how - but most of the examples and tutorials that I have been able to find on-line assume nice, neat delimiters that are not repeated - so appreciate any help that you guys can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use powerful [extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
              txt
0        Rd/MLERS
1              Rd
2              Rd
3  Rd/DLEPC/DLERS
4           SLERS
5           MLERS

In [32]: df['clsfr'] = df['txt'].str.extract(r'([^\/]+)', expand=True)

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
              txt  clsfr
0        Rd/MLERS     Rd
1              Rd     Rd
2              Rd     Rd
3  Rd/DLEPC/DLERS     Rd
4           SLERS  SLERS
5           MLERS  MLERS
```

Explanation:

RegEx `([^\/]+)` - means take anything except `/` (and until the first occurrence of `/`) into  the first group

Answer (score 2):

use `str.split` and `str[0]` to access the first split, this will still return the initial string even without the separator:

```
In [121]:
df["primaryEjecta1"] = df['text'].str.split('/').str[0]
df

Out[121]:
             text primaryEjecta1
0        Rd/MLERS             Rd
1              Rd             Rd
2              Rd             Rd
3  Rd/DLEPC/DLERS             Rd
4           SLERS          SLERS
5           MLERS          MLERS
```

Comment: Can also specify `maxsplit`, since he only needs the first part: `split('/', 1)`